# "Predefined set of computers", where to define?

Tags: windows, windows-firewall

In windows 8/10/Server 2012/Server 2016 "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security", when defining allowable addresses, I can select addresses/subnets, address-ranges, or a pull-down with "Predefined set of computers"

I'd like to bundle all our external sites in "Remote Corp Network", but where do I define the addresses?
[image]

My googling only leads to threads like this; no answer
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8c4c6b4a-dc24-4a66-920f-4df0f4e283ed/windows-firewall-with-advanced-security-scope-of-rules-remote-address-predefined-set-of-computers?forum=winserverPN

Answer (score 2):

I found a [Technet thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/26125329-e4a6-4bdf-996d-8e69674056a4/firewall-how-to-defined-predefined-set-of-computers?forum=w7itprosecurity) for you which suggests that it's not possible to define any other sets. It includes links to other references which provide guidance for using the GUI and Powershell which may provide you with the functionality that you require.

Comment: Broken link, archive.org doesn't have it either :( This might be a similar technet article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-technet-forums/4d2e4cce-ebc2-433c-8c7c-3e1bc5376471

Answer (score 0):

These are dynamically generated addresses, and the only description you'll find is that located in **[[MS-FASP]: Firewall and Advanced Security Protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fasp/55e50895-2e1f-4479-b130-122f9dc0265f)** in particular [**Section 2.2.21 FW_ADDRESS_KEYWORD**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fasp/d69ec3fe-8507-4524-bdcc-813cbb3bf85f).  The drop down list values correspond to one of the followsing, for example "Remote Corp Network" corresponds to FW_ADDRESS_KEYWORD_REMOTE_INTRANET

**FW_ADDRESS_KEYWORD_LOCAL_SUBNET**: Represents the collection of addresses that are currently within the local subnet of the computer.
**FW_ADDRESS_KEYWORD_DNS**: Represents the collection of addresses of the current DNS servers.
**FW_ADDRESS_KEYWORD_DHCP**: Represents the collection of addresses of the current DHCP servers.
**FW_ADDRESS_KEYWORD_WINS**: Represents the collection of addresses of the current WINS servers.
**FW_ADDRESS_KEYWORD_DEFAULT_GATEWAY**: Represents the collection of addresses of the current gateway servers.
**FW_ADDRESS_KEYWORD_INTRANET**: Represents the collection of addresses that are currently within the local intranet of the computer.
**FW_ADDRESS_KEYWORD_INTERNET**: Represents the collection of addresses that are currently not within the local intranet or remote intranet of the computer.
**FW_ADDRESS_KEYWORD_PLAYTO_RENDERERS**: Represents the collection of addresses of the current Digital Media Renderer devices as defined in [MS-DLNHND] section 3.3.
**FW_ADDRESS_KEYWORD_REMOTE_INTRANET**: Represents the collection of addresses that are currently within the remote intranet of the computer.
**FW_ADDRESS_KEYWORD_CAPTIVE_PORTAL**: Represents the collection of addresses of the current captive portal.

If you need anything more verbose then dochelp at microsoft needs to be emailed so their support team can make these more descriptive and perhaps add some examples.